# What is the easiest way to track down an Insert Into error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a rather large Insert Into . . Select . . From . . 
I have over 500+ lines of SQL in this script and I'm getting this error:

```
INSERT INTO MtgeMaster (  [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      ,[Col3]
      , etc., etc. )
SELECT  [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      ,[Col3]
      , etc., etc.
FROM MtgeMktg
```

When I run the code above I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 164
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

It looks like the error comes from line 164, but line 164 is literally my `[Col1]` field, and this is VARCHAR.  So, I'm going from VARCHAR to VARCHAR.  There is no VARCHAR to NUMERIC.

Also, if I add a couple of blank lines and re-run the process, I get this:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 166
>    Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

All it's really doing is going to the line with the `INSERT INTO` clause.

The error must be coming from another line, but it's hard to tell what's throwing the error when I have 500+ lines of SQL to go through.

Comment: There is no easy way, you just gotta start from the bottom up and work out which columns might apply and write some queries to find the bad data - if in fact its bad data, not a mistake with the query.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does not makes this easy.  I have found that a brute force approach is necessary.  I like to start by loading the data into a staging table where all the columns are strings.  This makes it easier to manipulate.

You can use one of two methods to find the error.  The first is to use `try_convert()` on each column to determine where the error is.

The second is to do a binary search to find the offending row.  Load the first half of the data to see if the error is there.  Then divide that half in half.  And so on.

Comment: This is what I do too ... just comment out 50% of the fields/values and see if that works. If yes, then the problem is in the other half. 
Keep doing this until you have only one field/value left which will be the problem. Why Microsoft can't tell us which field has the incorrect type has been a pain for years, and often appears on "wishlists" for SSMS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error before and after adding few blank lines is same. It is probably a datatype conversion issue. You could try using cast() function and convert the data type of the [Col1] in select field of MtgeMktg table to match with the datatype of [Col1] of the MtgeMaster table.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's my attempt to answer this question, based on what is given.

1. I would review the table structure of MtgeMaster, and see what columns are supposed to be numeric.  Let's just say, for this example, Col3 of MtgeMaster is numeric. You may have multiple numeric columns.
2. I would then query MtgeMktg and check whether the column you're trying to save from MtgeMktg to MtgeMaster is numeric or not.   You may have to do this for each column that is numeric in MtgeMaster. If I were doing it (which I did in SQLFiddle), it would be something to the nature of the following:

```
select * from MtgeMktg where ISNUMERIC(Col3) = 0
```

3. Anything that returns from this query will tell you what rows have a non numeric column.

Simple fiddle listed [here:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2635a/1/0)

Obviously, you would have 1 of 2 decisions to make at this point.   Fix the data, or filter out the rows that have the non-numeric data in it.  I presume you'd need the rows though.

Comment: I presume you may be able to filter multiple numeric columns in your where clause where necessary.

Comment: @ Tiny, I tried your suggestion and I see just 70 records causing issues.  Yeah!  Out of millions, that's not bad at all.  It's all 'N.A' and 'NULL'.  I tried this: CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Col3])<>0) THEN -1 ELSE [Col3].  That threw an error.  I just want a simple tag, or whatever indicator, to represent the bad records.  Now, I'm seeing this: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: I think you want to check if column does = 0. <> 0 will give you all numeric rows. You will need to end the case statement with END.